# Resolution of promise is not being fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code that does not solve the promise.

```js
let res = this.#xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      const that = this;
      if (that.#xhttp.readyState == 4 && that.#xhttp.status == 200) {
        res(that.#xhttp.response);
      }
    });
  }

res().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

How can I get the answer at the right time?

Comment: There's no reason for `that` in your code. You're using arrow functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `res` to the **function** that you're assigning to `onreadystatechange`. You want to set it to the promise.

The code you've quoted is at the wrong level. You want to create the promise a level further out, where you create the `XMLHttpRequest`. You haven't given me enough code to really help you do that, but it'll be something like:

```
function doARequest(/*...params...*/) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                } else {
                    reject(/*...whatever you want to pass, typically an Error...*/);
                }
        };
        xhr.open(/*...arguments...*/);
        // ...
    });
}
```

**But**, in any vaguely-modern environment, just use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) instead.

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve my problem by wrapping everything within the promise. Regarding fetch I have had multiple problems to do the same in requests, however with this old approach I have been able to solve my problems. Thank you!!